# Inexplicable 'undefined' timer variable causing TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, phaser-framework

I am trying to initiate a looped timer in phaser as follows in the `create()` function of my `Game.js` state:

```
    var jackpotTimer = new Phaser.Timer(this.game);
    jackpotTimer.loop(500, function () {
        this.jackpotSignal.dispatch(this.game.rnd,integerInRange(1000, 3000), this.game.rnd.integerInRange(10000, 20000));
    }, this);
    jackpotTimer.start();
```

At runtime, I receive the following error:

```
phaser-split.js:56360 TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined
at 429.Phaser.Timer.start (phaser-split.js:48661)
at __webpack_exports__.a.initJackpotSocket (RGSCommunicator.js:31)
at __webpack_exports__.b.create (Game.js:117)
at 429.Phaser.StateManager.loadComplete (phaser-split.js:8143)
at 429.Phaser.Loader.finishedLoading (phaser-split.js:55895)
at 429.Phaser.Loader.processLoadQueue (phaser-split.js:55847)
at 429.Phaser.Loader.asyncComplete (phaser-split.js:55923)
at 429.Phaser.Loader.jsonLoadComplete (phaser-split.js:56840)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (phaser-split.js:56345)
```

The line in Phaser.Timer.start that's breaking looks like this:

```
this._started = this.game.time.time + (delay || 0);
```

Using the chrome debugger, I have confirmed beyond reasonable doubt that at the time of the error:

1. `this.game` is correctly defined and can be explored in the "scope" window
2. `this.game` has a defined `time.time` property that can be found by exploring `this.game` in the scope window
3. mousing over `time` in `this.game.time` in the source code window yields "undefined."
4. The error is being caused by the timer instance quoted above.

I am at my wit's end as to what could be causing this. Has anyone seen this before?

I am using the [Phaser-ES6-Webpack](https://github.com/lean/phaser-es6-webpack) stack with Phaser CE 2.9.4

Comment: not familier with framework, but did you try starting your timer `jackpotTimer.start();` before you start the loop?

Comment: Just gave it a try - yields the same result.

Comment: Can you post the full error stack you are getting on console?

Comment: @Shaunak edited above

Comment: Have you made sure the `this` inside your loop is the same `this` as outside it? Like test it to make sure?

Comment: Outside the loop try writing `var vm = this;` and then replace `this.game` with `vm.game` in side the loop.

Comment: Gave it a shot, doesn't seem to change anything. I didn't try this originally because the third argument of timer.loop(), the callback context, shoudl take care of this:

Comment: https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Timer.html#loop

Comment: right, so `this.jackpotSignal` and `this.game` are both part of same 'this' context you passed to the function? if not they will conflict. if they are, then try removing the passed `this` and replace all three instances of `this.jackpotSignal` and two `this.games` with `vm.*`

Comment: I'm not familiar with phaser, but I ran you example in here : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPravp?editors=0110
and it seems to run just fine, did I miss anything in my example?

Comment: @Morta1doesn't look like the loop is actually running in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I found syntax that does not break and executes properly:

```
var self = this;        
game.time.events.loop(500, function () {
        self.jackpotSignal.dispatch(game.rnd.integerInRange(1000, 3000), 
game.rnd.integerInRange(10000, 20000));
        console.log("looped");
}, this);
```

The key here seems to be referencing `game` instead of `this.game`, as this variable seems to hold a special place in phaser that is rather unusual in javascript, since it usually requires explicit references. Still wondering about the unusual behavior observed in the debugger...